# viewpager is not showing in activity

Tags: android, xml

code of my XML file is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_exercise_one_questions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.joshiyogesh.puzzle.ExerciseOneQuestions">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="What Number Replaces Question mark ? "/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

initially it was showing , but after i added text-view in XML file its not showing in activity.
any help would be appreciated. Since I'm knew , i couldn't find the what exactly reason.

edit : 1 
**what it should be , there would be textView below which there would be PageAdapter**

Comment: set the linearLayout orientation to vertical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_exercise_one_questions"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="What Number Replaces Question mark ? "/>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what have you changed is "orientation" but , I don't wanna go for "vertical"

Comment: it can't be done with horizontal, if your textview width is match_parent.

Comment: what's a reason behind it.

Comment: what would i like to do is ... there would be textView below what there would be viewPager

Comment: vertical orientation is what will keep viewpager below the text. If you make the orientation horizontal, it sets it next to textview not below in view hierarchy and tv has already width math_parent, so viewpager doesn't show.

Comment: I couldn't get the logic of keep orientation horizontal still if you need it, you can make a Relative Layout as parent layout, set tv on top of it, make linearlayour (with horizontal orientation) below it and put you viewpager in it.

Comment: Now i got it :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code the linear layout orientation is vertical and you gave the textview(which is your first view) width = "match_parent" means it ll take all the available width and then you are adding your viewpager(which doesn't have any space remained). Change android:orientation="vertical" to android:orientation="horizontal" and it ll work.